# How to get a list of recently edited files?

Tags: c#, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Last week, Microsoft released the **new Graph API** to the public (after being in preview for a few months) exposing Office365 data via REST. As everything is still relatively new, there are only few tutorials & documentation available.

I am looking for a way to get a list of all **recently opened/edited files**, much like e.g. the OneDrive app does & shows me. From the [documentation](https://graph.microsoft.io/docs), I know how to get files and the last change date. However, there is maybe a more efficient way to get the most recent files, **rather than recursively iterate** through every folder and have a look at the files.

Do you have any ideas?

There is also a request for files trending around me (`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/trendingAround`), but the results are just some public files, also shown on Delve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in the graph, you would use:

/v1.0/me/drive/recent

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's possible using the Microsoft Graph but it's definitely possible using the SharePoint Search REST API by issuing the following request:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='isdocument:1'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Microsoft promotes the Graph API as the one API to get all the data from Office, Sharepoint, usw - so this should be possible to achieve too with the new API. I tried to adapt your query to the new API, without success. The documentation is very limited and there are very little tutorials in the web. I didn't find any hints about filtering/querying (https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/drive). The search feature (https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_search) is maybe the right thing, but I can't make it work...

Comment: You would need to execute the query just as I mentioned changing the tenant name to your tenant (ie. yourcompany.sharepoint.com). Currently SharePoint Search is not a part of Microsoft Graph which is why you cannot execute the query through it. The good news is that you can use OAuth to get a valid access token to execute the query from your app.

Comment: We'll be adding support for the "recent" file list through OneDrive API (and thus Graph API) over the next few months.

Comment: Will it support getting recent files from across Office 365 or only from your OneDrive for Business (or separately for each drive)?

Comment: @RGregg Good to know. So, to solve my request now, I use the SharePoint Search REST API, as suggested by Waldek?

Comment: Yes, that's the answer available today @casaout.